# My azure pipeline fails with my NugetCommand on several packages in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml, mediatr

as seen in the title my azure pipeline fails with the following log

> ##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1202: Package MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 10.0.1 is not
> compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0). Package
> MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 10.0.1 supports:
> netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

I can post more but the messages are the same for other packages such as Automapper and EntityFrameworkCore.

I'm using the following steps in my YAML file.

> steps:
>
> - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0   displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.1.0'   inputs:
>   versionSpec: 5.1.0
> - task: UseDotNet@2   displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 5.0.x'   inputs:
>   version: 5.0.x
>   includePreviewVersions: true
> - task: NuGetCommand@2   inputs:
>   restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My azure pipeline fails with my NugetCommand on several packages in Azure Devops

To resolve this issue, please try to use the latest nuget version:

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet '
  inputs:
    checkLatest: true
```

If still have this issue, try to disable nuget restore task and add the 'dotnet restore' task.