# NuGet Restore Fails - .NET 7.0 compatibility with .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: .net, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

I have a solution with a .NET 7.0 ASP.NET project which has a project reference on a .NET Standard 2.0 library in the same solution.  All builds and executes fine on my machine.

I have a Pipeline in Azure DevOps that builds the projects and aims to deploy the ASP.NET project to a server.  Before building, it runs the task `NuGetCommand@2` to execute a NuGet Restore against `**/*.sln`.  This is being run on the `windows-2022` Azure VM Image.

The restore bombs because of errors like these:

```
Package Microsoft.OpenApi 1.4.3 is not compatible with net70 (.NETFramework,Version=v7.0). Package Microsoft.OpenApi 1.4.3 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

```
Errors in D:\a\1\s\MyApp.csproj
    Project MyLibrary is not compatible with net70 (.NETFramework,Version=v7.0). Project MyLibrary supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

This reads to me like it's saying you can't consume .NET Standard 2.0 libraries in a .NET 7.0 project, but the compatibility docs seem to claim otherwise.  What's going on here?

Comment: The restore of Microsoft.OpenApi works on your machine?

Comment: @promicro - Yes, it appears to.  I've cleared my NuGet cache and rebuilt the entire solution, and not only do the restore and build work, but the app operates without any runtime error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My azure pipeline fails with my NugetCommand on several packages in Azure Devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72875716/my-azure-pipeline-fails-with-my-nugetcommand-on-several-packages-in-azure-devops)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update on 12/3**

During the investigations and referencing on this issue, I found this ticket [Github_Nuget_Tool_Cache_issue#16800](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/16088), more developers are confused with this by-design behavior.

So far, the only workaround seems to be the extra installation of `6.4.x`.

You could also raise a [feature request ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?) to raise more concern for future update on this behavior.

================================================================

**Original post on 12/1**

I installed the latest `nuget` version of `6.4.0.123` with `nuget tool installer` [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-tool-installer-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) to ensure the compatibility for Microsoft.OpenApi 1.4.3 with net7.0.

======================================================

**updated on 12/2**

From the source page of [Microsoft.OpenAPI.1.4.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OpenApi/1.4.3#supportedframeworks-body-tab), this version is designed to be compatible with DotNet 7.0.

During the investigations, I look into the debug logs, I found that the nuget restore task is using the cache version with `4.x` in window-2022. And I suppose that this version is surely not compatible with dotnet 70.
[image]

After installing the later nuget version to `6.4.x`, everything is compatible.
[image]

So I suppose the nuget version could be the key to result in the different behavior. (even maybe by design that the `Nuget 4.1` could not recognize the compatibility between `Microsoft.OpenAPI1.4.3` and `Dotnet 7.0`)

**Reference**

[NuGet 4.9 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-4.9-rtm)

[NuGet 5.11 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-5.11)

[NuGet 6.4 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-6.4)

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate more on why this is needed? Does the window-2022 image not have a new enough NuGet installation? Why does this NuGet version know how to resolve this restore issue and older ones cannot?

Comment: @bubbleking hi, is your issue resolved? If not, you could share more latest details with me. I have also updated my answer.

Comment: This seems rather absurd.  The specs for the windows-2022 agent lists NuGet 6.4.0.123 as being installed, per the below link.  Is there a way to break this "tool cache?"  It seems odd to have to wait for a task to run on all of my builds just to get NuGet up to date.

https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md

Comment: @bubbleking hi, it's a pity that this seems to be a by-design behavior observed among many developers, and yet there haven't been an easier workaround than the installation. To be more frank, I am also very confused with the behavior. If my answer helped, you could [accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to share with more developers

Comment: Indeed.  I was able to get things going using the NuGet installer task, and it only added about 5 seconds to the Pipeline.  Further research confirmed there doesn't appear to be any other way to do it.  Answer accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Ceeno's answer, but including example implementation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-tool-installer-v1?view=azure-pipelines

I just opted to get the latest version.

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Update NuGet'
  inputs:
    checkLatest: true
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the introduction to this answer because I am running YAML pipelines, and the doc linked by @Ceeno shows the YAML.  However, I think there is value to this, because the link in the original answer is buried in a bit of a text wall, whereas this answer clearly provides it, as well as an immediately visible YAML snippet for those looking to cut to the chase.  Upvoted.

Comment: Edited for accuracy. I didn't click on every link but I got the jest and indeed just wanted to provide an implementation.